# DirectX Render to a texture

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm trying to implement a rendering to a texture but without success. I've created a class that will(should) take care about all these stuff:

```
class TextureRenderer
{
public:
    TextureRenderer() = delete;
    TextureRenderer(ID3D11Device *pDevice, int width, int height);
    ~TextureRenderer();

private:
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView *pResView;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView *pRenderTargetView;
    ID3D11Texture2D *pTexture;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView *pTarget;
    Texture *pCTexture;

public:
    void BeginRender(ID3D11DeviceContext* pDeviceContext);
    void EndRender(ID3D11DeviceContext *pDeviceContext);
    void Clear(ID3D11DeviceContext *pDeviceContext, ID3D11DepthStencilView *pDepth,
        Vector4 clearColor);

    Texture *GetTexture()   { return pCTexture; }
};
```

**Declarations:**

```
TextureRenderer::TextureRenderer(ID3D11Device *pDevice, int width, int height)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
    D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc;
    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;


    ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));
    textureDesc.Width = width;
    textureDesc.Height = height;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    HRESULT hr = pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, nullptr, &pTexture);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw directx_init_error(hr, "Texture2D");

    // Setup the description of the render target view.
    renderTargetViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
    renderTargetViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    hr = pDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pTexture, &renderTargetViewDesc, &pRenderTargetView);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw(directx_init_error(hr, "RTV"));

    shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

    hr = pDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(pTexture, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &pResView);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw directx_init_error(hr, "shader resource view");

    pCTexture = new Texture(pResView);
}

TextureRenderer::~TextureRenderer()
{
    if (pCTexture)
    {
        delete pCTexture;
        pCTexture = nullptr;
    }

    if (pResView)
    {
        pResView->Release();
        pResView = 0;
    }

    if (pRenderTargetView)
    {
        pRenderTargetView->Release();
        pRenderTargetView = 0;
    }

    if (pTexture)
    {
        pTexture->Release();
        pTexture = 0;
    }
}

void TextureRenderer::Clear(ID3D11DeviceContext *pDeviceContext, ID3D11DepthStencilView *pDepth,
    Vector4 clearColor)
{
    float color[] = {
        clearColor.x, clearColor.y, clearColor.z, clearColor.w
    };

    pDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(pRenderTargetView, color);
    if (pDepth)
        pDeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(pDepth, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
}

void TextureRenderer::BeginRender(ID3D11DeviceContext *pDeviceContext)
{
    ID3D11DepthStencilView *pDepthStencil = nullptr;
    pDeviceContext->OMGetRenderTargets(1, &pTarget, &pDepthStencil);

    pDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &pRenderTargetView, pDepthStencil);
}

void TextureRenderer::EndRender(ID3D11DeviceContext *pDeviceContext)
{
    ID3D11DepthStencilView *pDepthStencil = nullptr;
    pDeviceContext->OMGetRenderTargets(0, nullptr, &pDepthStencil);

    pDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &pTarget, pDepthStencil);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
pTextureRenderer->Clear(pDeviceContext, nullptr, Vector4(0, 0.25f, 0.333f, 0));
pTextureRenderer->BeginRender(pDeviceContext);
....
pTextureRenderer->EndRender(pDeviceContext);

p2DObject->SetTexture(pTextureRenderer->GetTexture());
p2DObject->Render(pDeviceContext);
```

Texture class just hold a pointer to `ID3D11ShaderResourceView`.
When I'll try to render this texture, nothing happens. Texture and D2DObject classes are ok(everything else is rendered correctly)

Comment: Have you tried adding return codes to each call to see where (if) it is failing e.g. `hr = pDeviceContext->OMGetRenderTargets  if (FAILED(hr))...`

Comment: Standard debugging advice for Direct3D applications: Check all HRESULTs returned from functions that are not ``void``--the Direct3D methods that can't fail return ``void``, the methods that return HRESULT can fail so you need to check them all with ``FAILED`` or ``SUCCEEDED`` macros--; enable the [Debug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) device and check for error/warning messages, and failing that use a graphics debugger like the VS 2013 graphics diagnostics features in VS 2013 Express for Windows, VS 2013 Community, or VS 2013 Pro+.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I've created the debug device already and nothing shows up except warning about default sampler state which is valid so. Also I'm using VS 2013 Pro